# vsc не выводит с++ код

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

а вот что выводится в терминале:

```
C:\cpp> cmd /C "c:\Users\name\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.15.4-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe --stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-u5hviej1.xwm 
--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-twna21yu.lev --stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-sxfns2jy.dq0 --pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-ynymmbra.nzt --dbgExe=C:\mingw64\bin\lldb.exe --interpreter=mi "
```